# Unbestimmter und Nullartikel

Tags: article

Ich habe heute gesagt:

1. Das war reiner Zufall
2. Ich will heute möglichst viel erledigen, um reines Gewissen zu haben

Sind diese Sätze richtig und klingen gut?

Ich versuche seit Kurzem häufiger den Nullartikel zu nutzen, damit mein Deutsch an Natürlichkeit gewinnt, und nicht wie bisher nur grammatisch korrekt bleibt. Noch bis Kurzem - bevor ich neue Dinge über den Nullartikel erfahren habe - hätte ich den unbestimmten Artikel genutzt:

- Das war ein reiner Zufall
- Ich will heute möglichst viel erledigen, um ein reines Gewissen zu haben

Habe ich meinen Übergang auf den Nullartikel gekonnt umgesetzt?

Answer (score 2):

1. Das war reiner Zufall *<= Das ist korrekt und klingt gut.*
2. Ich will heute möglichst viel erledigen, um reines Gewissen zu haben. *<= Das ist leider nicht korrekt.*

Korrekt wäre für 2. nur:

> ... um ein reines Gewissen zu haben.

Der bestimmte Artikel funktioniert hier auch nicht. Man könnte aber alternativ sagen: "... damit mein Gewissen rein ist."

Was Du in der eigenen gelöschten Antwort über zählbare Substantive geschrieben hast, ist grundsätzlich der richtige Weg, um zu ermitteln, ob man den Artikel weglassen kann.

Beim "Gewissen" ist es so, dass jede Person ihr eigenes hat, und zwar genau eins. Und bei Wörtern, bei denen das so ist, sind  Formulierungen à la "Ich habe ein reines Gewissen" mit der Bedeutung "Mein Gewissen ist rein" üblich, immer mit dem unbestimmten Artikel.

Andere Beispiele:

> Ich habe eine gesunde Schilddrüse. (= Meine Schilddrüse ist gesund.)
> Die Kirche hat einen großen Magen... *(aus Goethes "Faust")* (= Der Magen der Kirche ist groß.)
> Anna hat eine erhöhte Körpertemperatur. (= Annas Körpertemperatur ist erhöht.)

Aber:

> Anna hat Fieber.

Das steht ohne Artikel, denn das kann nicht entsprechend umformuliert werden. *Fieber* ist nicht etwas, was zu jeder Person gehört.